# Which mode is the best for taking pictures: manual, auto, or portrait?

Tags: camera-settings, camera-basics, shooting-mode

Which one is the best mode for taking pictures: manual, auto, or portrait? Or if any other mode is better, please state what it is.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you need to ask, use "auto".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days I have my camera in Manual the majority of the time. Most of the time the light doesn't change much so I can pick the aperture I want (for a desired depth of field) adjust the ISO as needed to set an exposure and leave it there. The only time I need to change that is if the light changes or I have a new requirement for the aperture.

The advantage of this is if compose shots with different amounts of bright (windows) or dark (shadows) the exposure will not change and your subject will still come out exposed as you want.

If the light is changing a lot then I would switch to aperture mode so I can still control the depth of field and let the camera pick the shutter speed.

So, for me the choice is manual followed by aperture mode as a second most popular mode.